# SQLite Trigger is updating every row, instead of selected rows

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have `TableA` with `col1 ,col2` with both `Col1` and `Co12` are currently `NULL`.

I'm trying to create `TRIGGER` to update `Col2` when `Col1` changes to not `NULL`.

This is the trigger I have so far, however on `UPDATE` it is updating every row in `TableA.Col2` to `11` ... not just the row that has been changed:

```
CREATE TRIGGER trigger1 
AFTER UPDATE
ON TableA
WHEN NEW.date_back IS NOT NULL
AND OLD.date_back IS NULL  
BEGIN 
    UPDATE TableA 
    SET Col2 = 11;
END;
```

Comment: Your update lacks a where clause. A trigger does not provide one for you.

Answer (score 1):

Your update lacks a where clause. There is no implied where clause just because the query is inside a trigger.

Assuming your table has an id column...

```
CREATE TRIGGER trigger1 AFTER UPDATE ON TableA
WHEN NEW.date_back IS NOT NULL
 AND OLD.date_back IS NULL  
BEGIN 
  UPDATE TableA SET Col2 = 11 where id = new.id
END;
```